# Use LonLat coordinates to perform queries on API

Tags: openlayers, geojson, api, vector-layer

I'm programming a map with OpenLayers (4.6.5) and I use this API :

https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api

What I want to do is `/reverse/`, I want to retrieve coordinates that I'm using in my popup (see my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKvJwq)) to perform a query like this :

https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357

With my code I'm retrieving a lon-lat table. How could I separate my two coordinates and integrate it in my request ? Should I create a vector layer (the API is returning GeoJSON files) or an http request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make an Ajax call using `fetch` (it could also be the "old" `XMLHttpRequest`, more a question of preferences)

The relevant code you need to change is the following

```js
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  // ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate) return an array of two elements
  // We use destructuring e.g https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
  var lat, lon;
  var [lon, lat] = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
  fetch(`https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=${lon}&lat=${lat}`).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
    console.log(json.features[0].properties.label);
      content.innerHTML = '<p>Adresse : ' + json.features[0].properties.label + ' </p><code>' + lon + ' ' + lat +
      '</code>';
  });
  overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
});
```

You can see [a new demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKKYVW) forked from your sample